# Enhanced Scroll Bar for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

If you have experienced working with Enhanced Scroll Bar of Productivity Tools of VS2010, you know it's nearly impossible to work without it anymore. Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support it. I've googled but found nothing interesting. Maybe you have heard of some alternatives that work with Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: I am still using visual studio 2010 and didnt knew about the feature. Now I am using it and addicted to it already. +1 for that.

Comment: A lot of the features in Productivity Tools for VS2010 were rolled into VS2012, but apparently not this feature. Hopefully there will also be a Productivity Tools for VS2012.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, Productivity Power Tools 2012 was released yesterday: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/11/07/productivity-power-tools-2012.aspx

Comment: Direct link to the Visual Studio gallery: [Productivity Power Tools 2012 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd?SRC=VSIDE).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option to look at - if you're an early adopter : )

The [ProgressiveScroll](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/873d4c86-7827-4d51-95e9-6eb44c0d3287) extension in the Visual Studio gallery.

On Sept 16 2012 the developer posted:

> The extension **should now be compatible with VS 2012**. I am not actively
>   testing it in VS 2012 though, so if you try it out and find any bugs,
>   be sure to let me know.